# Neural network predicted value

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms

I am starting to learn about machine learning as a whole and have found a big interest in Neural Networks. My question today is, 
Given a **simple** cost function $J$ with weights $w1, w2$ and inputs $m1, m2$ and a target prediction/error $b$ so that $J = w1*m1 + w2*m2 + b$.

Lets say we want to develop an algorithm that can detect by the heights and length of the flower pedal which color the flower was. To save time I have already seen clustering in the graph and the red flowers which are close to 1 while the blue are close to 0.

Most cost function outputs go from 0 to 1 (I think due to the sigmoid function), 1 being yes or some desired output = red and 0 being no or another desired output = blue.

Now, what if instead of looking at two different colors (red and blue) what if our Machine wants to analyze 10 colors given the heights and length of the pedals? Would we say that if the output of the cost function was 2.1 (2 being green) it would be green for example or if its 5.2 (5 being yellow) its yellow? 
Not sure how to analyze more than two things if we can only go from 0 to 1 due to the sigmoid function.

Comment: I think you have mixed up a few things. Your **J** is not a typical cost function, the formula you have given looks more like a predicted value in a linear regression. That predicted value might be used in an actual cost function, but is usually given a different name such as $\hat{y}$. Then **J** would be related to differences between $\hat{y}$ and the true value $y$, often this is averaged over multiple data samples. This level of confusion in the question makes it hard to answer things as written.

Comment: I am looking over some youtube tutorials and they gave this example here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6NBkkKNZXw   I was just basing my knowledge off of this and some online excerpts.

Comment: The video looks correct to me. It does not give the cost function that you have written. You have missed a step, what you have given is the formula for making a linear regression prediction. The cost function inspired from the video might be written $\hat{y} = w_1 m_1 + w_2m_2 + b$, $J = (\hat{y} - y)^2$ for a single example. More usually you would write  $J = \frac{1}{2N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(\hat{y}_i - y_i)^2$ to cover a whole data set (and halving it is a convention that just makes maths easier later)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With binary classification (your first example) you use a sigmoid function at the end, where the value indicates the probability P(Red), and 1-value equals the probability of P(Blue). Because there are only two classes we can use one value because together they sum to one. By using binary crossentropy loss we can fit our model. When you have to deal with more than two classes having one value is not enough anymore. What you do then is to have **n** output values that are mapped to a probability distribution using the softmax. This comes down to taking the e-power of all of them and then normalizing them to sum up to 1. By using the multiclass crossentropy loss which is the generalized version of the binary crossentropy loss we can still estimate this.

EDIT: Where with binary classification we map using the sigmoid:

$$P(Red) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-Wx}}$$

Now we have a probability for all colors individually:

$$P(Color = y) = \frac{e^{W_yx}}{\sum_{c\in C}e^{W_cx}}$$

Comment: can you elaborate a little more on mapping my outputs to a distribution using the softmax? I am not sure what the softmax is and what type of distribution do we use (normal, poisson...etc?) Thank you!

Comment: Jan van der Vegt, Thank you so much that makes more sense now!